# What is Subversion best-practice for harvesting from invalid working copies following restoration of an old repository backup?

Tags: svn, backup

I have some questions about restoring to an old subversion repository backup.

Suppose that there are various working copies (wc) based at a revision in a certain repository (repo). The repository might be at revision 100, say, and the working copies BASEd at various revisions, say 80, 60, 40:

```
repo @100
wc-1 @80
wc-2 @60
wc-3 @40
```

Now suppose that there's a disaster, the repository is lost, and the most recent valid backup available is a bit old, say to revision 50. This is restored, and the situation is now this:

```
repo @50
wc-1 @80 X
wc-2 @60 X
wc-3 @40 ?
```

The working copies marked 'X' are now obviously invalid. Their BASE does not exist.

It is not possible to *down-date* (i.e. update downwards) the invalid working copies, as the required delta no longer exists in the repository. It would not be desirable to do this in any case, as such working copies might be the only existing source of the lost revisions.

Further, suppose that following the restoration of the repository, there is no process in place, and the following is allowed to happen.

Working copy 3 is *apparently* fine. (Well, it really is fine when considered in isolation, but perhaps it should not be touched until things have been sorted out *globally*.)

Its owner now gets up-to-date, and commits several sets of changes, bringing the repository's HEAD revision to 70. The situation is now this:

```
repo @70
wc-1 @80 X
wc-2 @60 X!
wc-3 @70 ?
```

Working copy 2 is now in a confused state. The revision 60 of its BASE is **not** the same as it was originally. However, it may not be obvious that it is invalid. The apparent differences between this working copy and the repository are a mixture of real local changes, of differences introduced by working copy 3, and differences representing the lost revisions. That is, it's a mess.

So my questions are as follows:

(1) How well does SVN behave in this respect? Specifically, how will SVN respond to wc-1's attempts to commit? How will SVN respond to wc-2's attempts to commit (once the repository HEAD is beyond wc-2's BASE)? Is this documented anywhere?

(2) Are there documented best-practice procedures for restoring to an old SVN repository backup, for identifying invalid working copies, and for trying to "harvest" the lost changes from the various invalid working copies that exist?

(Presumably, part of the answer is that as soon as a repository has been recovered, all invalid working copies should be abandoned as working copies, and their changes transferred to fresh checkouts, and that *all* working copies should be put on hold until a recovery plan is in place.)

Thanks.

Comment: I'm following this question with interest. However, it seems difficult to answer: as far as I know, Subversion does not even have a tool to verify a working copy ("svn cleanup" is not such tool).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing something but I do not see a problem here.

User with working copy which is at revision 80 does the following

1. Leaves this working copy untouched (this is the "pristine" wc)
2. Checks out a new working copy which is at a lower revision (e.g. 50 or 70) (this is clone wc)
3. Copies manually all files from the pristine wc to the clone wc
4. Commits all changes from the clone wc to the "recovered" repository

All other users checkout (after this is done) to a completely new wc. All other wc can be discarded (the ones before the disaster).

Now everybody is at "revision 80" (in reality 51 or 71) which is the best possible scenario since this was the higher revision after the disaster.

The point is that regardless of numbers everybody gets the best/latest version of files available.

This way you don't even have to care on how "subversion behaves in this respect"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Essentially you are correct.

There is very real potential for a problem. If a user who is unaware of the repos 'rollback' tries to update a working copy, his 'lost' changes could be spoilt. This is particularly a problem when the resurrected repository has new revisions that have moved on beyond the user's base.

I am concerned with coordinating members of large software engineering teams.

I'm sure there must be many companies out there that have had to deal with this problem. I wondered whether anyone has already come up with a documented 'recovery process'.

Comment: My questions about SVN's behaviour are still relevant. SVN will show an error that a "revision does not exist", but I think it has no checksum to validate a working copy base against a repository revision. One potential idea is that the SVN administrators keep the partially recovered repository off-line until the recovery procedure has been communicated to all users (which in itself might not be that easy, with remote users in other timezones and users on holiday).

Comment: Yes you right! My solution assumes clear communication between all stakeholders. In a truly large company where co-ordination is not trivial I guess that you would have to be careful. Perhaps someone with svn internals knowledge can answer the technical part of your question.